# Grunt task dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs

I have a grunt task that is installed via npm `taskA` (not the actual name)

taskA has a dependency: grunt-contrib-stylus and that is specified in taskA's package.json and installed. For some reason when running **grunt default** from the main Gruntfile.js it gives an error.

`Warning: Task "stylus" not found. Use --force to continue.`

And the fix is to require grunt-contrib-stylus in the main project. I want to avoid this. What would be the reason that my task is not using the grunt-contrib-stylus in its node_modules/ ?

**taskA**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
'use strict';

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');
...
```

**main Gruntfile.js**

```
...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('taskA');
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grunt.loadNpmTasks` loads `[cwd]/node_modules/[modulename]/tasks/`. You can load task as dependenies by changing the `cwd`:

**taskA**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var parentcwd = process.cwd();
  process.chdir(__dirname);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');

  process.chdir(parentcwd);
};
```

Just be sure to set the `cwd` back to the parent at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a seemingly simple way to do this using node-isms. Even with [kyle-robinson-young](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17597886/169491)'s answer, if your task depends on another task via peerDependencies or is in a nested structure you'll still receive the warning.

Here's a way around that!

In your **taskA**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('grunt-contrib-stylus/tasks/stylus')(grunt);
  // Other stuff you need to do as part of your task
}
```

Grunt doesn't appear to care if a task is attached via `registerMultiTask` or `registerTask` more than once.